# JLabel wont change Width

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

I'm programming right now a Chomp Game for Uni. Everything works fine but the Label at the bottom. Its background is supposed to fill out the entire bottom. In the attachment you can see how it instead looks now. I tried setting the minimum and the preferred size of the label. The Height is changing but the width just stays adjusted to the text. How can I change that?

Note: The snippet only contains the setting up of the Frame and Panels in a custom method and not the main class.

```
private void init()
    {
    JFrame fenster = new JFrame();
    this.spielfeld = new SpielfeldPanel(M, N);
    this.anzeige = new SpielerAnzeigeLabel(this.spieler);
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    BoxLayout boxlayout = new BoxLayout(panel,BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);
    panel.setLayout(boxlayout);
    fenster.setTitle("Chomp");
    fenster.setSize(1000,700);

    panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1000, 60));
    Dimension d = new Dimension(getPreferredSize());
    panel.setMinimumSize(d);
    panel.add(spielfeld);
    panel.add(anzeige);
    fenster.add(panel);


    this.spielfeld.setVisible(true);
    this.anzeige.setVisible(true);
    panel.setVisible(true);
    fenster.setVisible(true);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);




    }
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qDfBM.png]

Answer (score 1):

A `BoxLayout` respects the width of the component to the label is displayed at its preferred width/height.

A JFrame uses a BorderLayout by default. So just add the label to the frame independently of the panel:

```
//panel.add(anzeige);
//fenster.add(panel);
fenster.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
fenster.add(anzeige, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
```

The PAGE_END constraint respects the height but makes the width equal to the space available. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use BorderLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html) for more information and examples.